# Displaying and saving Django ArrayField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have an a type of `ArrayField` in a model.  The backend in a list of suggested elements for `my_list` automatically.  However, the user then needs to update this list as needed.  The model looks like this:

```
class my_model(models.Model):
    my_list = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=10)
    )
```

The problem is that when `my_list` is rendered in the template is a single html input tag with a comma separated list.  For example `a,b,c,d`.

My question is two fold.  How can I get the templating language to display the comma separated list so that each element has their own html input box. Moreover, the harder thing that I am struggling with is how to make it so that these elements will be saved back to the model back as an array.

My current thinking is to hack the front-end with javascript.  But is there a better way to do it with Django?

Comment: Are you sure you want a separate `input` for each element? Would a single `select` not be better? How would users add anything to the list?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what is your exact goal but it can be something like this:

```
{% for element in my_list %}
    <div> {{element}} </div> <!--any html tag which you desire--> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: but when I press save, it doesn't save it back to the model properly

Comment: you should post your code here then others can help because now its so vague that what is your intention

Answer (score 1):

You need to create and register a custom [Widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/).

> A widget is Django’s representation of an HTML input element. The widget handles the rendering of the HTML, and the extraction of data from a GET/POST dictionary that corresponds to the widget.

A simple example that will render a multi-line textarea:

```
class ArrayWidget(Textarea):
    def format_value(self, value):
        if value is None or len(value) == 0:
            return None
        else:
            return '\n'.join(value.split(','))

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        return data.get(name).splitlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create several fields with name attribute 'myfield' for example. Then in the View you can get a list of that fields using request.POST.getlist('myfield') and you can iterate it in a loop for and store it in an arrayfield. 2 Years later but i hope this solve your question.